# Java Quicksort Book's Partition Stack overflow

Tags: java, stack-overflow, quicksort

So i'm getting a stack overflow when i'm just over 10,000 to sort.

I'm doing a book's partition with a random pivot.

```
   public static void QuickSortbookRand(int[]a, int low, int high) //random pointer, book's partition
   {
      int le = low, diff = high-low, i=0;
      Random rn = new Random();
      if (diff > 0)
      {

         int pivloc = rn.nextInt(diff + 1) + low;
         switchnum(a, pivloc, high);
         pivloc = high;
         int piv = a[pivloc];
         for (i = low; i<high; i++)
         {
            if (a[i] < piv)
            {
               switchnum(a, i, le);
               le++;
            }
         }
         switchnum(a,le,pivloc);
         pivloc=le;
         /*
         if (diff < 2 && high > 10700)
         {
            System.out.println("high:" + high + ",low:" + low + ",pivloc:" + pivloc);
         }
         */
         if(low < pivloc)
         {
            QuickSortbookRand(a, low, pivloc-1);
         }
         if(high > pivloc+1)
         {
            QuickSortbookRand(a, pivloc+1, high);
         }
      }
      return;
   }
```

i get an error at this point when i uncomment the test print statement:

```
high:10708,low:10707,pivloc:10707
high:10711,low:10710,pivloc:10710
high:10714,low:10713,pivloc:10713
high:10719,low:10718,pivloc:10718
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at ArraySorts.QuickSortbookRand(ArraySorts.java:155)
    at ArraySorts.QuickSortbookRand(ArraySorts.java:155)
    at ArraySorts.QuickSortbookRand(ArraySorts.java:155)
    at ArraySorts.QuickSortbookRand(ArraySorts.java:155)
```

I need the app to run on a 10,000,000 element array. Is there any way to make less recursive calls?

using insertionsort for all arrays under 10 elements.

```
high:10188,low:9689,pivloc:9689
high:10188,low:9690,pivloc:9690
high:10188,low:9691,pivloc:9691
high:10188,low:9692,pivloc:9692
high:10188,low:9693,pivloc:9693
high:10188,low:9694,pivloc:9694
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.nio.cs.ext.DoubleByte$Encoder.encodeLoop(DoubleByte.java:514)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:561)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:271)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:526)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:806)
    at ArraySorts.QuickSortbookRand(ArraySorts.java:161)
```

Comment: You can (and should) delegate to insertion sort for lists under 10 items - it'll likely perform faster.

Comment: Edited main post with what happens when i use insertion sort for all subarrays under 10 items.

Comment: I can't get your code to stack overflow. I sorted an array with 10,000,000 elements. Any more details?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FEyaif13

that is the test program i'm running. It seems to work fine on most arrays.

there are other sort methods but i only have trouble with the ones that use book's partition.